# Storing AM/PM time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, cgi

I have the following code:

```
  sprintf(aCommand,"insert into Schedule 
     set StartTime = TIME(STR_TO_DATE(%s,"%h:%i %p")), 
     EndTime = TIME(STR_TO_DATE(%s,"%h:%i %p")),
     DayofWeek = '%s', 
     Activity = '%s %s %s'",arr[2],arr[3],arr[1],arr[0],arr[4],arr[5]);
```

I have the table `Schedule` with columns: `StartTime`, `EndTime`, `DayofWeek` and `Activity`. I have a time in string which has this format: `10:00 AM`. My query above gives me error. How can I store that format to `time` data type which is in `10:00:00` in MySQL?

EDITED: This is the new code.

```
 sprintf(aCommand,"insert into Schedule
 set StartTime = TIME(STR_TO_DATE(%s,'%h:%i %p')), 
EndTime = TIME(STR_TO_DATE(%s,'%h:%i %p')), 
DayofWeek = '%s',Activity = '%s %s %s'",arr[2],arr[3],arr[1],arr[0],arr[4],arr[5]);
```

This gives me the error:

```
mp1a.c: In function ‘main’:
mp1a.c:45:4: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘:’ in format [-Wformat]
mp1a.c:45:4: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat]
mp1a.c:45:4: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘:’ in format [-Wformat]
mp1a.c:45:4: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 7 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat]
mp1a.c:45:4: warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat]
mp1a.c:45:4: warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat]
mp1a.c:45:4: warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat]
mp1a.c:45:4: warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat]
```

Comment: you are mixing up double quotes, can you use single quotes in between like before "%h??

Answer (score 1):

Just to format it better, forgive me if this isnt the answer

```
sprintf(aCommand,"insert into Schedule 
     set StartTime = TIME(STR_TO_DATE('%s','%h:%i %p')), 
     EndTime = TIME(STR_TO_DATE('%s','%h:%i %p')),
     DayofWeek = '%s', 
     Activity = '%s %s %s'",arr[2],arr[3],arr[1],arr[0],arr[4],arr[5]);
```

This is formatted properly, and adding the exact error message you get would help to fix further

Comment: Submitted an edit to add single quotes to the `STR_TO_DATE(%s`.

Comment: @StephenO'Flynn I've edited the question and inserted the errors. What could be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, my edits did not go through yet. In @skv's solution, you must make a further change, putting single quotes around the `%s` in both `STR_TO_DATE` statements:

`STR_TO_DATE('%s',`

Comment: Is that fine now @StephenO'Flynn and thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
DATE_FORMAT(%s,'%l:%i%p') instead of STR_TO_DATE
```

for reference check this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: It gives me warning: `unknown conversion type character`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%h:%i %p')
```

[**Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/18755)